# I dont't understand about how hashmap put value in?

Tags: rust

Code 1:

```
let mut scores = HashMap::new();
let x = scores.entry(String::from("MC")).or_insert(10);
println!("{:?}",scores);
println!("x={}",x);
```

Code 2:

```
let text = "this world is a wonder full world";
let mut map = HashMap::new();
println!("{:?}",text.split_whitespace());
for i in text.split_whitespace(){
    let count =  map.entry(i).or_insert(0);
    *count +=1;
}
println!("{:?}",map);
```

I have 2 questions:

- Why is the scores in code 1 can't be print but the map in code 2 can be print?
- In code 2, what is the purpose of count?
  With *count +=1 i, i have: {"this": 1, "a": 1, "wonder": 1, "world": 2, "is": 1, "full": 1}
  Without *count +=1, i have: {"world": 0, "wonder": 0, "is": 0, "a": 0, "full": 0, "this": 0}

Comment: you need to read the error messages. For first one you have a mutable reference and a reference at the same time which is invalid by rust borrowing rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the scores in code 1 can't be print but the map in code 2 can be print?

Lets look at the compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `scores` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:22
  |
5 |     let x = scores.entry(String::from("MC")).or_insert(10);
  |             ------ mutable borrow occurs here
6 | 
7 |     println!("{:?}", scores);
  |                      ^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
8 |     println!("x={}", x);
  |                      - mutable borrow later used here
```

You are taking a mutable reference on `x` and an inmutable one in the first print to the same thing. This is invalid by rust borrowing rules.
One way of changing it would be to use a custom scope so the mut reference is dropped after used:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let mut scores = HashMap::new();
    {
        let x = scores.entry(String::from("MC")).or_insert(10);
        println!("x={}", x);
    }
    println!("{:?}", scores);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a86f8f061359374982bfd43ea222178e)

In there `x` is droped after the scope is finish so it validates referencing `scores` again.

As per:

> In code 2, what is the purpose of count?

`*count +=1;` just updates the corresponding item in the `Hashmap` by increasing its value by `1`.
Basically it is counting words. If you remove it, then, for any word you are just creating a default value of 0 at `map.entry(i).or_insert(0)`.

Comment: i'm wondering: in the code 2, in for loop, i put the code (println!("map={:?}",map);) under the code (*count +=1;) - there is no error although it violated borrowing rule

Comment: @phuchung, xin chao!, It is the same problem as case one. You are already borrowing a `&mut` in the entry, so you cannot reborrow the map for the print.